# Linq Group by / Distinct with Join table

Tags: linq, join, group-by, distinct

i plan to join 2 table, and get the distinct value of language column. How should i achieve that in Linq? I try add 'group' but no luck. Besides, i want to select s value too together with r distinct language value.

My code:

```
 public ActionResult QuestionLink(int Survey_ID)
        {
            var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model
                        on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
                        where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
                        group r.language << this is not work **
                        select r;

            return PartialView(query.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: what result are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what in [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) is called `DistinctBy`. But if that method works on `IEnumerable`, so you can't use it in an EF query. But you can use the same approach:

```
var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
            join s in db.SURV_Question_Model on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
            where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
            group new { r, s } by r.language into grp
            select grp.FirstOrDefault();
```

But I wonder if this really is what you want. The result depends on the ordering of languages that the database happens to return. I think you should add a predicate for a specific language and remove the grouping:

```
var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
            join s in db.SURV_Question_Model
            on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
            where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
               && r.language == someVariable
            select new { r, s };
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Is it possible to select 2 value which is select grp.FirstOrDefault and r ?

Comment: sorry @gert arnold, my mistake, i want select s too. Possible something like select new {grp.FirstOrDefault() , s }  ?

Comment: On the other hand, if `SURV_Question_Ext_Model` and `SURV_Question_Model` are related by navigation properties, that could improve a few things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model
                        on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
                        where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
                        group new {r, s} by r.language into rg
                        select rg.Key;
```